# How to parse Ruby Code using IronRuby?

Tags: ruby, c#-4.0, ironruby

I am new to IronRuby. I am trying to integrate it with C#.

I have created following example and it is working fine.

```
string rubyCode = @"
                    def function_111(test)
                       print 1
                    end                   
            ";
 ScriptEngine engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();            
 ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
 engine.Execute(rubyCode, scope);
 dynamic sayHelloFun = scope.GetVariable("function_111");
 sayHelloFun("test");
```

If you look at above code then I am using execute method that compile and execute code but instead of that I only want to parse code it means its syntax are correct or not.

How can that possible ?

Comment: Googling for "IronRuby parser" turns up this: http://zianet.dk/blog/2010/02/28/getting-the-ast-from-ironruby/

Comment: It really help me. It solve my issue.

Comment: And, the link is dead. This is why just a link is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

The link posted appears dead, and the search engine cache copies appear to be rotting, so I'm going to scrape what is left of the post and interpret it below.

---

You can use [IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/) along with the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) to parse the Ruby code. The steps are to: create a Ruby engine instance, create a script source and unit, create a parser and parse to an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), and walk the AST with a [Walker](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/ipy-2.7-maint/Languages/Ruby/Ruby/Compiler/Ast/Walkers/Walker.cs).

### Create the Engine

```
var runtime = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateRuntime();
var engine = runtime.GetEngine("rb");
```

### Create the Source Unit

```
var src = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(@"puts 'hello'"); // also: engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile
var srcUnit = HostingHelpers.GetSourceUnit(src);
```

### Parse

```
var parser = new Parser();
var srcTreeUnit = parser.Parse(srcUnit, new RubyCompilerOptions(), ErrorSink.Default);
```

### Walk the AST

```
var walker = new MyWalker();
walker.Walk(srcTreeUnit);
```

You'll need to subclass the [Walker](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/ipy-2.7-maint/Languages/Ruby/Ruby/Compiler/Ast/Walkers/Walker.cs) class, which has numerous virtual methods to handle visiting various nodes in the AST. The one used in the [LinqPad Query](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/ipy-2.7-maint/Languages/Ruby/Ruby/Compiler/Ast/Walkers/Walker.cs) looks like so:

```
public class MyWalker : Walker
{
    protected override void Walk(MethodCall node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method call: " + node.MethodName);
        base.Walk(node);
    }

    protected override void Walk(StringLiteral node)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("String Literal: " + node.GetMutableString().ToString());
       base.Walk(node);
    }
}
```

When you run this walker on the AST generated above, you get the following:

```
Method call: puts
String Literal: hello
```

I used [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and added the IronRuby 1.1.3 nuget package and created a [LinqPad Query](http://share.linqpad.net/inf9no.linq) with the above.